Is it possible for two users to receive the same nonce-generated ID in a Solidity smart contract?
I have a smart contract deployed on the Ethereum blockchain where each user who interacts with a specific function is assigned an ID based on a nonce value stored in the contract. The nonce is incremented after each assignment. My concern is whether there could be a situation where two users might end up with the same ID due to some race condition or other issue in the contract.
Could this happen under normal circumstances, or are there specific scenarios I should be aware of to prevent this? I'm particularly concerned about reentrancy, concurrency, and gas-related issues. Any advice on how to ensure the uniqueness of these IDs would be appreciated.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract UniqueIDAssigner {
    uint256 private nonce; // Nonce for generating unique IDs
    mapping(address => uint256) public userIDs;

    function assignID() external returns (uint256) {

        uint256 assignedID = nonce;
        userIDs[msg.sender] = assignedID;

        
        nonce++;

        return assignedID;
    }
}


@syed-asad-kazmi could you please answer to this question if you know ?

Please share your code.

@zartaj-afser i have updated the question,you can check it

No, as the nonce is increasing every time, there's no case when two users get the same ID. It's similar to counters in any NFT contract.
Apart from this, some additional info: There should be a check to see if a user already has an ID assigned, otherwise, they can call the function infinitely, getting new IDs each time.
This might affect the whole logic, considering it is a project running in production.
EDIT:
Question: I have such edge case situation.Lets suppose first user calls the function before confirmation of tx second user also calls that function,so in that moment the ID shouldnt be same for both users ?
This won't happen, as Asad mentioned in the comments, the transactions are executed synchronously, which means any one of the two transactions will be executed before, and the state changes will occur as per the first transaction, which means during the execution of the second transaction, the nonce is already increased.

I have such edge case situation.Lets suppose first user calls the function before confirmation of tx second user also calls that function,so in that moment the ID shouldnt be same for both users ?

@SYEDASADKAZMI can you provide any appropriate material to read more in detailed ?

@NersesAsaturyan, sorry, in the previous comment, I’d mistakenly used the term "asynchronously", but it’s "synchronously".
So, the assignment of nonce would be done synchronously, ensuring that the same values won’t be assigned to different users/txs.

You can refer to this post, mentioning about the synchronous state change.

@SYEDASADKAZMI thanks a lot
